# How to prove that every uniformly continuous set is a closed set.

Tags: education

According to the classroom notes "Uniformly Continuous Linear Set" in American Mathematical Monthly, Vol. 62. No. 8(Oct., 1955) pp. 579-580, Author: Norman Levine [link](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2307254?uid=2134&uid=2473528133&uid=2&uid=70&uid=3&uid=2473528123&uid=60&sid=21102554033503).

I'm usually confused about the state "without loss of generality".

Let see the proof of theorem 1.
From the proof of theorem 1, how does "WLOG" work?

Thanks for all answers.

Comment: Relevant part of the proof mentioned in question is shown in [another post by the OP](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/468050/how-to-verify-that-f-is-continuous-while-not-uniformly-continuous-itself/).

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Uniformly continuous functions can be extended continuously to their completions. If $p$ is a limit point of $X$, consider the function

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{d(x,p)}$$

Comment: Sorry for asking again, in the proof of theorem 1 how to verify that f(x) is continuous but it's not uniformly continuous.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need the statement:

> If a convergent sequence is not eventually constant, then it has a strictly monotone subsequence.

You read it in$\,$ C.G.Denlinger *Elements of Real Analysis* $\,$[pag. 113](http://books.google.com/books?id=5YhXVE9slLsC&pg=PA113).

**Addendum** (referring to my comment to prove the not uniformly continuity of $f$) the convergent sequence is a Cauchy sequence; therefore there exist always two terms $p_r$ and $p_s$, whatever near, such that $|f(p_r)-f(p_s)|=1$. Take $\epsilon<1$ ...

Comment: thanks it's very useful but now in the proof of theorem 1) I cannot find the way to verify that f(x) is continuous but it's not uniformly continuous. Thank you for your help.

Comment: WLOG is related **only** to the existence of the sequence ... Have better edit your question.

Comment: You need to find an $\epsilon>0$ such that for every $\delta>0$ there are points $u$ and $v$ in $E$ such that $|u-v|<\delta$ and $|f(u)-f(v)| \ge \epsilon$.